# get related object but not via foreign key

Tags: django, orm

I have the following models in my django app.

```
class EndUser(models.Model):
    end_user_id = models.CharField

class EndUserField(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField
    value = models.CharField
    user = models.ForeignKey("EndUser", null=False, verbose_name=_('end user'))
```

An EndUser can have many EndUserFields.
In some situations, if a certain EndUserField is queried, I would like to be able to fetch another field.

I tried the following, but it does not work:

```
(
    EndUserField.objects
    .filter(name='x')
    .select_related('user')
    .prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'user__enduserfield_set',
            queryset=(
                EndUserField.objects
                .filter(
                    name='y'
                )
            ),
            to_attr='user_name'
        )
    )
)
```